# How to create click counter (with database) in Meteor?

Tags: javascript, database, meteor

This should be a relatively simple solution, but it's been a long time since I've done any programming and I'm a bit rusty. Basically, I'd like to create a simple page with a counter, which increases in value by 1 when I click a button. This is how the default Meteor app is set up, but doesn't include a database model for the data to persist in. Basically, I want the number to stay at the value to remain even if I leave the page. How do I go about doing this?

So far, I have created a Schema like this:

```
counter = new Mongo.Collection('counter');

counter.attachSchema(
    new SimpleSchema({
    clicks: {
      type: Number
    },
    createdAt: {
      type: Date,
      denyUpdate: true
    }
  })
);
```

And a button with the following JS attached:

```
Template.home.events({
  "click .increment": function (event) {
    counter.update({
      clicks: "++",
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: There's quite a few ways... The question is basically how to retain data after a client has left the app. It's very broad. I think you need to add some more info, such as: Do you use accounts? Do you want to store this data on the server, or on the client? Also, that is not how you increment a counter in Mongo at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct update method to increment the field `clicks` by one would be `{$inc: {clicks: 1}}`, for example: `Counter.update({_id: counterDoc._id}, {$inc: {clicks: 1}});`.

Here's a demo:

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
    Template.home.events({
        "click .increment": function () {
            var counterDoc = Counter.findOne();
            if (counterDoc) Counter.update({_id: counterDoc._id}, {$inc: {clicks: 1}});
            else Counter.insert({clicks: 1});
        }
    });

    Template.home.helpers({
        clicks: function () {
            var counterDoc = Counter.findOne();
            return counterDoc ? counterDoc.clicks : "0";
        }
    });
}
```

---

```
<template name="home">
    {{clicks}}
    <br/>
    <button type="button" class="increment">Increment</button>
</template>
```

---

```
Counter = new Mongo.Collection('counter');

Counter.attachSchema(
    new SimpleSchema({
        clicks: {
            type: Number
        },
        createdAt: {
            type: Date,
            denyUpdate: true,
            autoValue: function () {
                if (this.isInsert) return new Date;
                else if (this.isUpsert) return {$setOnInsert: new Date};
                else this.unset();
            }
        }
    })
);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Unfortunately the counter itself isn't showing (yet), but I'm assuming this has to do with the fact that I'm not publicizing or subscribing correctly.

Comment: @zenben1126 You are welcome! Yes, this might be the case. Could you please open the browser's console and run `Counter.find().fetch();` to see if you can access the counter's document on clients?

Comment: Matthias I figured it out :) My subscription in IronRouter was off. Danke